# Can malware write to a completely blank dvd-r/+r?

Tags: dvd

Can malware write to a completely blank dvd-r that has never been used yet, but has only been put into the computer's optical drive (on an infected computer)?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't exclude this possibility but it's kinda far-fetched, besides nowadays optical disks have almost completely lost their appeal and most laptops and even computers come without a DVD drive.

Any DVD burning application/utility is just a normal application which can be replicated or included by malware.